# Совместное использование NSString и NSMutableString

Tags: xcode, objective-c, macos

Есть код:

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText = ...;
NSMutableString *str =  [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
str = [[inputText stringValue] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
```

1) Xcode выдает **предупреждение** на 3 строке:

> Incompatible pointer types assigning
> to 'NSMutableString *'from 'NSString*
> '

Насколько я понял - Xcode предупреждает о том что *"substringWithRange"* возвращает *NSString*, а у меня получатель *NSMutableString*. Но мне нужен именно *NSMutableString*, так как содержимое *str* в программе меняется. Но также хотелось бы удовлетворить Xcode. Как исправить ошибку?

2) Почему метод *[str release]* перечеркнут красным в Xcode? Что это означает?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
NSMutableString *mutStr = [str mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText = ...;

NSString *str = [[inputText stringValue] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
```

Далее создаете новый изменяемый стринг и делайте с ним все что вам угодно.

```
NSMutableString *mutStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
```

Comment: 2) потому, что используется ARC и освобождать переменную самостоятельно уже нет необходимости.

Comment: Это создает копию str в mutStr. Мне дальше нет необходимости менять mutStr. Дальше будет идти подобный код: 
str = [[inputText stringValue] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
То есть уже с другими параметрами для NSMakeRange. Другими словами необходим один и тот же объект для работы с substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(..., ...) на протяжении всей программы.

Comment: можете показать весь кусок кода? не могу уловить логику вашего решения.

Answer (score 0):

Просто выполните приведение типов

```
str = (NSMutableString *)[[inputText stringValue] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
```

Перечеркнут красным, потому что ваш проект с ARC - который сам поставит release